# Calling default web page of application automatically in Spring Boot

Tags: java, html, spring-boot

I am a Spring Boot newbie and one thing bothers me: if I have a simple Spring Boot application like this:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

I can call the default web page of the application from a browser by using URL:

`http://localhost:8080/greeting`

To return a page called `greeting.html` which is specified by the controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting() Model model) {            
        return "greeting";
    }
```

Is there a way to have Spring Boot automatically open `greeting.html` in the browser? Can I tell Spring boot which controller method I want it to run when the project starts?

Comment: This is more of a IDE configuration question than an Spring boot question, you should tag it with the IDE you're using

Comment: Would you know the relevant NetBeans setting at all?

Comment: Are you asking how to set up welcome page? *"automatically open greeting.html in the browser"* is not something a server-side framework would do.

Comment: Yes, this is true but if I run other web applications and specify a welcome page in web.xml I knwo this page will load. So I am seeking to do the same here.

Comment: Thanks to the respondents. I will return to this tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is a setting you can set for this case but what you can do is using redirection.

Just map `"/"` and redirect to `"/greeting"`:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String index(Model model) {            
    return "redirect: greeting";
}
```

But if you want that the browsers open any page after lunching the application you should lookup if your IDE can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Just map your greeting page to the root:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String greeting() Model model) {            
    return "greeting";
}
```

Then when you call http://localhost:8080/ you will be redirected to the greeting page as a default page.